# Databricks Pyspark: How to get the list of tables in external MySQL and create data frame?

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

Working in Azure Databricks, Pyspark.
I need to connect to an external MySQL server ABC database and copy all the tables under the database to Azure Databricks.
I wrote the below codes and it only returns the number of tables in that database.

pip install pymysql

```py
import pymysql

con=pymysql.connect(host='XXXXX', password='XXXXX', port=3306, user='my_username', charset='utf6', database='ABC')

cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute('show tables')
```

it only returns Output: 41

How can I get the list of tables in that database?
How to create dataframe for these 41 tables by batch?

hope to get the list of table names under ABC database

hope to create data frames for these 41 tables by batch and stored in databricks dev database

Comment: list of tables: `cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES;')`

Comment: for the dataframe what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this and it works fine for me:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pymysql

# Establish a connection to the MySQL server and retrieve the table names
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='XXXXX',
    port=3306,
    user='my_username',
    password='XXXXX',
    charset='utf8mb4',
    database='ABC'
)

cursor = connection.cursor()

# Retrieve table names
cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
table_names = [table[0] for table in cursor.fetchall()]

cursor.close()
connection.close()

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MySQL to DataFrame") \
    .getOrCreate()

databricks_database = "dev"

# Iterate over table names and create data frames
for table_name in table_names:
    query = f"SELECT * FROM ABC.{table_name}"
    df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://XXXXX:3306/ABC") \
        .option("user", "my_username") \
        .option("password", "XXXXX") \
        .option("dbtable", query) \
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
        .load()

    # Save data frame as a table in the Databricks database
    df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(f"{databricks_database}.{table_name}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! the only error shows when create data frame, it shows"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: @Emma, you need to make sure that your spark cluster has the driver installed. reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html